# How to append form input data as string to form action url

Tags: html, forms, mailchimp

I have a mailchimp form I need to populate with content from simple html form on my website.

I read in mailchimp [documentation](http://blog.mailchimp.com/how-to-pre-fill-items-on-your-mailchimp-hosted-form/) that this is quite possible by appending query vars to the url.

So I need something like this:

```
http://mb30.us7.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=e0bf770a88286aad599b3e945&id=f3cc462828&MERGE1=name&MERGE2=June%205th%20-%208pm%20EST/5pm%20PST&MERGE0=mail
```

And I need to get url above, from form below:

```
<form action="http://mb30.us7.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=e0bf770a88286aad599b3e945&amp;id=f3cc462828" method="post" name="" target="_blank" novalidate="">
      <h5>1. Which day do you want to attend?</h5>
      <select name="time" style="display: none;">
            <option value="May_20th_-_8pm_EST/5pm_PST">May 20th - 8pm EST/5pm PST</option>
            <option value="May_25th_-_8pm_EST/5pm_PST">May 25th - 8pm EST/5pm PST</option>
            <option value="May_29th_-_8pm_EST/5pm_PST">May 29th - 8pm EST/5pm PST</option>

      </select><div class="ddContainer" style="position:relative;"><a href="#" class="ddToggle" style="width: 200px;">May 20th - 8pm EST/5pm PST<span></span></a><ul class="ddOptionList" style="display: none; top: 48px; width: 223px;"><li class="ddOption"><a class="selected" href="#" rel="May_20th_-_8pm_EST/5pm_PST" style="padding-left: 4px;">May 20th - 8pm EST/5pm PST</a></li><li class="ddOption"><a class="" href="#" rel="May_25th_-_8pm_EST/5pm_PST" style="padding-left: 4px;">May 25th - 8pm EST/5pm PST</a></li><li class="ddOption"><a class="" href="#" rel="May_29th_-_8pm_EST/5pm_PST" style="padding-left: 4px;">May 29th - 8pm EST/5pm PST</a></li></ul></div>

      <h5>2. Where to send the invitation:</h5>
      <input type="text" class="inputbg" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Your Name') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your Name';}" value="Your Name">
      <input type="email" name="EMAIL" class="inputbg" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Your Email Address') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your Email Address';}" value="Your Email Address">
      <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

But I cannot get it to work, if I change form to get, than required u= and id= get deleted.

Comment: Change the &amp; to a & in the URL and what is the problem with using POST?

Comment: @jabbink it doesn't autopopulate mailchimp form, user has to input name and other fields by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the values to the URL, create hidden `<input>`s for those values. That's what [this example](http://mailchimp.us1.list-manage.com/subscribe?u=d7ef9398dbcac36cd9e03a31f&id=7de7e9f7d8&group%5b5%5d%5b1%5d=true&group%5b5%5d%5b4%5d=true) also does (view the source).

```
<input type="hidden" name="u" value="e0bf770a88286aad599b3e945" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="f3cc462828" />
```